# Trying to add two different strings in PHP

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins, sidebar

I came up with an solution for not showing an sidebar in Wordpress when this is not filled with widgets. I did this by calling for the slug from the current page and named my sidebars the same as the slugs from my pages.

I use the Custom Sidebars plugin to add sidebars. This plugin adds 'cs-' in the id of a sidebar before the name of the sidebar. So for example I've named my sidebar 'Test' than the id of the sidebar will be 'cs-test'.

Now I want my php code to check if the sidebar is named the same as the slug from the page. So I called `the_slug` and before the slug I want to add `cs-`. With some help I came up with this:

```
<?php if ( is_active_sidebar( 'cs-'.the_slug(false) ) ) { ?>
    <?php dynamic_sidebar( is_active_sidebar( 'cs-'.the_slug(false) ) ) ?>
    <?php } else { ?>
<?php } ?>
```

But that doesn't seems to help. Any thoughts how to fix this? Thanks already!

Comment: This has nothing to do with jQuery. What am I missing?

Comment: I am sorry. You are totally right! My bad. I think I wasn't awake adding that tag.

Comment: Hi Nick please check the_slug(false) function return cs-test proper.

Comment: @renishkhunt yes it did. And it works when I use `is_active_sidebar( print 'cs-' .  the_slug(false) )` but then the slug also appears besides the sidebar. So that is not the right solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your are concatenating a string `cs-` with a function `the_slug(false)`. This **might** cause the error, depending on what the function is returning.

**Solution 1:**

You could  call and save the function beforehand and concate two vars:

```
<?php 
$slug = the_slug(false); //Get return value
$slug = (string)$slug; //Force string conversion
$slug = 'cs-'.$slug; //Concate

if ( is_active_sidebar( $slug ) ) { ?>
    <?php dynamic_sidebar( is_active_sidebar( $slug ) ) ?>
    <?php } else { ?>
<?php } ?>
```

.

**Solution 2:**

If you need this type of functionality often try to add a string parameter to the `the_slug()` function (should be a custom function in your functions.php) and do the concatenating within the function itself:

```
function the_slug($boolen, $string='') {
    //Your code

    return $string.$your_var;
}
```

Your sidebar code would look like this:

```
<?php if ( is_active_sidebar( the_slug(false, 'cs-') ) ) { ?>
    <?php dynamic_sidebar( is_active_sidebar( the_slug(false, 'cs-') ) ) ?>
    <?php } else { ?>
<?php } ?>
```